# How to select elements of a vector properly?

Tags: r

Why does filtering elements of a vector with '[]' results in NA, while 'which' function does not return any NA?

Here is an example:

```
setor <- c('residencial','residencial',NA,'comercial')
setor[setor == 'residencial']
#"residencial" "residencial" NA`

setor[which(setor=='residencial')]
#[1] "residencial" "residencial"
```

Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you use `==` for comparison it returns `NA` for NA values.

```
setor == 'residencial'
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE    NA FALSE
```

and subsetting with `NA` returns `NA`

```
setor[setor=='residencial']
#[1] "residencial" "residencial" NA
```

However, when we use `which` it doesn't count `NA`'s and returns index of only `TRUE` values.

```
which(setor=='residencial')
#[1] 1 2

setor[which(setor=='residencial')]
#[1] "residencial" "residencial"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `%in%`, which returns `FALSE` where there are `NA` elements

```
setor %in% 'residencial'
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

It also works when we need to subset more than one element, i.e.

```
setor %in% c('residencial', 'comercial')
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

and this can be directly used to subset

```
setor[setor %in% 'residencial']
#[1] "residencial" "residencial"
```